# NPM install is failing to clone the git repo on win10

Tags: git, npm

I have Git repo which i clone it during npm install, Package.json includes the git url.
everything works fine on win7 setup but on Win10 i am facing this issue,
Not sure what i am missing here.

```
Package.json:
{
"name": "main",
"version": "0.0.1",
"main": "index.html",
"devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.18.0",
    "ld-gxp-tools": "git://git-mirror:9418/gxp/tools#master",
```

Error i am getting:

```
npm WARN package.json main@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result                    (git://git-mirror:9418/gxp/tools)
npm ERR! git clone git://git-mirror:9418/gxp/tools Cloning into bare            repository 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-git-mirror-9418-gxp-tools-1dc087b5'...
npm ERR! git clone git://git-mirror:9418/gxp/tools fatal: Unable to look up     git-mirror (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: git clone --mirror git://git-    mirror:9418/gxp/tools C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-git-mirror-9418-gxp-tools-1dc087b5
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository     'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-git-mirror-9418-gxp-tools-1dc087b5'...
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to look up git-mirror (port 9418) (No such host is     known. )
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
npm ERR!     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! command     "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\environment\\win32\\node\\node.exe"     "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\environment\\win32\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-    cli.js" "install"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you resolve this hostname from your client machine:

```
git-mirror
```

If not, then the git clone won't work.

That's what this line requires:

```
"ld-gxp-tools": "git://git-mirror:9418/gxp/tools#master",
```

Comment: aaah yes it does not resolve, win7(working) and win10 nodes are exactly same and on same network, Not sure why win10 node has issue, but yeah we know why its not working.Thanks for quick response